# How to get feeds from Facebook in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7, facebook-graph-api

I want to create an app in Windows Phone 7 which one of the features must be to get feeds from Facebook pages and then show them in a listbox control in an xaml page, then the user can do things like post, view comments, etc… What is the easier way to do this? Are there any sample projects to download?

Answer (score 2):

Here you have a good talk about what you are looking for

[How to access facebook API using Windows Phone 7](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/82139/495693.aspx)

Comment: Thank you... I will check this resource, I have seen that there are a complete solution in c# with Facebook integration. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Facebook API to do this. Documentation for mobile developers is here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/

If you're looking for a complete solution to your problem that you can just copy-and-paste, that's not really what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: Thank you Brian for your answer but this I has this URL before I post my question. In this URL there aren't any mention to windows phone integration. I don't want copy/paste solution, only any help is that I need, I worked with iOs and I have an app that integrate Facebook api.